# how to bind Pre-populated data from object to radio button in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am working on Angular 5 application. I got radio button for Gender which value is pre-populated radio selection based on value it receving and I need to know how to use ng-if inline in html template. GenderType: string where value 1 is for male and 2 for female.

I have tried *ngIf but its not working out

```
 <div class="k-form-field">
     <span>Gender</span>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="k-radio" *ngIf:{{respondent.genderType='1'}} === checked="checked" disabled>
           <label class="k-radio-label" for="female">Female</label>

          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="k-radio" disabled>
             <label class="k-radio-label" for="male">Male</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's not how you write ngif. It's `*ngIf=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final answer that works for me

```
<div class="k-form-field">
    <span>Gender</span>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="k-radio" [attr.checked] ="respondent.genderType=='2' ? 'checked' : null" disabled>
      <label class="k-radio-label" for="female">Female</label>

       <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="k-radio" [attr.checked] ="respondent.genderType=='1' ? 'checked' : null" disabled>
       <label class="k-radio-label" for="male">Male</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ngIf to change the value form a property. You can just use a block of javascript for a conditional attribute:

```
<input 
   type="radio"
   name="gender"
   id="female"
   [attr.checked]="respondent.genderType=='1' ? 'checked' : null" />
```

Another option is to use forms in an "Angular way", either with [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) or with [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: getting error compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 23 in [respondent.genderType='1' ? 'checked' : null...

Comment: My code had a typo, I have fixed it. It should be == instead of = (in other words, a comparison and not an assignment).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming genderType 1 is female and 2 is male, you only has to bind that in the checked attribute. You don't need the ngIf. NgIf is to display or hide a html element. Try with this (also I removed the disabled attribute):

```
<div class="k-form-field">
     <span>Gender</span>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" class="k-radio" [attr.checked]="respondent.genderType === '1' ? 'checked' : null">
          <label class="k-radio-label" for="female">Female</label>

          <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="k-radio" [attr.checked]="respondent.genderType === '2' ? 'checked' : null">
          <label class="k-radio-label" for="male">Male</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: getting error compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 23 in [respondent.genderType='1' ? 'checked' : null

Comment: You are assigning not comparing. Check my example is with === not =

Comment: Ok, that is because is a number, not string so it has to be === 1