# Radio button checked with boolean attribute

Tags: boolean, radio-button, angular8, checked

Using angular 8, I am generating a list of user context where the user can select his connection context. As one of the context proposed is always the current context, I want to be able to check the radio button when current context is true, so on the user context dropdown opening, the current context is automatically checked.

Problem is, I can't find a way to bind the checked property to a boolean. Something like : 
checked="currentUser.currentContext".

```
          <tr *ngFor="let reworkedCollabspace of reworkedCollabspaces; let i = index">
            <td>
              <input type="radio" name="selectUserContext" id="checkBox{{i}}"
                     (click)="updateSelectedCollabspace(reworkedCollabspace, i)"
                     (change)="enableChangeContextBtn()">
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul>
                <li>{{ reworkedCollabspace.domain }}</li>
                <li>{{ reworkedCollabspace.organization }}</li>
                <li>{{ reworkedCollabspace.role }}</li>
                <li>prefered : {{ reworkedCollabspace.prefered }}</li>
                <li>current : {{ reworkedCollabspace.current }}</li>
                <li>selected : {{ reworkedCollabspace.selected }}</li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best approach I found is the use of

```
[attr.checked]="respondent.genderType=='1' ? 'checked' : null"
```

Plus to wrap the radio into a form. See those 2 related posts for more information :

- [how to bind Pre-populated data from object to radio button in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934978/how-to-bind-pre-populated-data-from-object-to-radio-button-in-angular-5)
- [Radio Buttons "Checked" Attribute Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606657/radio-buttons-checked-attribute-not-working)